# How do I explicitly set a rails engine routing proxy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On my Rails 5.0.7 application I have Thredded (0.15.4) mounted as an engine in a namespace.

```
#routes.rb

namespace :home do
  mount Thredded::Engine => "/communities", as: "thredded"
end
```

This allows me to access /home/communities to pull up the thredded interface.

Unfortunately, this also leads to unexpected behavior.  The rails route proxy is not `thredded` as expected, but rather `home_thredded`.  If I wanted to access a named route inside my engine, I need to do `home_thredded.root_path` instead of `thredded.root_path`

This is especially troublesome because `thredded.root_path` is actually referenced in the code of the thredded gem itself, which now throws an error.

Is there some way to explicitly set the routing proxy to avoid needing to include the namespace in the routing proxy?

A few things that I've considered and rejected:

1. I could directly edit the code in the offending file of the gem, but that would be annoying to maintain.
2. I could also write a decorator that overwrites the offending method so that it uses the correct rails routing proxy, but that would still mean that I would have to use the `home_thredded.some_path` anywhere rather than the expected `thredded.some_path`
3. I could not namespace the engine.  This could work, but it would break the naming conventions of the rest of the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
scope :home do
  mount Thredded::Engine => "/communities", as: "thredded"
end
```

That should add `/home` to your URI Pattern but leave your `Controller#Action` and `Prefix`s unchanged.

Comment: Ah, that worked.  The namespace is used for other resources, but it looks like rails can handle a scope which is the same as a namespace.